# android custom scheme and chrome intent

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, xamarin

I have a cross platform app developed in Xamarin. In the iOS version I use a custom url scheme to load a specific web page in a web view, such as

> myapp://?returnUrl=http:/google.com.au

As a customer has few other applications from us, he wants to keep the custom scheme in the same format. In the android I found that such intent can be opened from Firefox, but not form email or Chrome. I found that [Chrome needs a custom intent to make it work](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). I tried to implement that but couldn't make it work.

Here is my manifest implementation:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp",
    MainLauncher = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "myapp")]
```

wich will create a following manifest file:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:label="MyApp" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="myapp.auth.droid.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I tried to capture an intent from Firefox and convert it to URI in the application, but following intent is not working from Chrome (it works from Firefox BTW):

> myapp://?returnUrl=http:/google.com.au#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;launchFlags=0x4400000;component=MyApp.MyApp/myapp.auth.droid.MainActivity;end

Am I missing something?

**NOTE**. http:// scheme can be used but it is not a preferred option.

**NOTE 2**. I use Nexus 5, Android 4.4.4

Comment: can you put a dummy host there, or just an extra slash, `myapp://dummy/?returnUrl...`

Answer (score 2):

for chrome, you need to use the chrome intent, the old way is no longer supported in the after version 18

The intent should look like something in this format

```
intent://some_optional_data#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=package_name;end
```

check out this site for more detail information: [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

This method would also fall back to google play as well

Comment: I can use the old way with Chrome 36.0.1985.131 apparently.

Comment: This answer is useless. It doesn't explain the components of the url. Android Intents with Chrome is also a terrible document.

Comment: You have a better one? @caleb

Comment: is it working in 2019? please explain answer in more details.